# All Shopify Plan name enums list?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

It was there in community earlier that the enum list was mentioned. But this question in the community got archived. Putting this for question so that it travels parallelly (without getting archived hopefully)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was there in a community post earlier and now it has been archived. So this is the list of last known values -

```
[
"affiliate",
"staff",
"professional",
"custom",
"shopify_plus",
"unlimited",
"basic",
"cancelled",
"staff_business",
"trial",
"dormant",
"frozen",
"singtel_unlimited",
"npo_lite",
"singtel_professional",
"singtel_trial",
"npo_full",
"business",
"singtel_basic",
"uafrica_professional",
"sales_training",
"singtel_starter",
"uafrica_basic",
"fraudulent",
"enterprise",
"starter",
"comped",
"shopify_alumni"
]
```

Also there is a `partner_test` value that signifies a dev store created by a Shopify Partner account.

Reference post - https://web.archive.org/web/20221205155748/https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/enumeration-of-plan-name-from-get-admin-shop-json/m-p/273626